# C# multiplication not occurring?

Tags: c#, multiplication

I'm baffled - looking at this incredibly simple code and can't find why when i enter a value for r (radius of a circle) the return value for area and perimeter is r?! It just won't calculate? Sorry for the stupid question. Is it because i want the return value with only 2 digits after the floating point?

```
Console.Write("Enter the circle's radius r: ");
double r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double perim = (2 * Math.PI * r);
double area = (Math.PI * (Math.Pow(r, 2)));
Console.WriteLine("The circle perimeter is: {0:2}", perim);
Console.WriteLine("The circle area is: {0:2}", area);
```

Comment: The multiplication is fine, how you're showing it is wrong. If you stepped through this in a debugger, that would have been clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `{0:0.00}` instead of `{0:2}` for your format specifier.

```
Console.Write("Enter the circle's radius r: ");
double r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double perim = (2 * Math.PI * r);
double area = (Math.PI * (Math.Pow(r, 2)));
Console.WriteLine("The circle perimeter is: {0:0.00}", perim);
Console.WriteLine("The circle area is: {0:0.00}", area);
```

For more info see: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Custom numeric format expects characters such as: `0`, '#', and other specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , all others characters are copied to the result.

`2` is not specified in the list, it doesn't mean 2 digits after decimal instead it will copied to the result. So what ever would be the result of calculation, the output will have `2`

Comment: Or {0:N2} if you want to use standard format specifiers